# Conversion of decimal[ ] to double [ ] in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mschart

I am making plots in `asp.net-mvc4` application using following code

```
System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();

        chart.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        chart.Width = Unit.Pixel(700);
        chart.Height = Unit.Pixel(420);
        chart.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(211, 223, 240);
        chart.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
        chart.BackSecondaryColor = Color.White;
        chart.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.TopBottom;
        chart.BorderlineWidth = 1;
        chart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
        chart.BorderlineColor = Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);
        chart.RenderType = RenderType.BinaryStreaming;
        chart.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
        chart.AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.All;
        chart.TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.Normal;

        Series series1 = new Series("Series1");
        series1.ChartArea = "ca1";
        series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        series1.Font = new Font("Verdana", 8.25f, FontStyle.Regular);

        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint
        {
            AxisLabel = "Value1",
            YValues = new double[] { 100 }
        });

        series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint
        {
            AxisLabel = "Value2",
            YValues = new double[] { 500 }
        });

        chart.Series.Add(series1);

        ChartArea ca1 = new ChartArea("ca1");
        ca1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(ca1);

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            chart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/png", "mychart.png");
        }
```

Now I have my data points as an array from database saved in `returnValue`. I added edited data point as below

```
series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint
        {
            AxisLabel = "Value1",
            YValues = new double[] {returnValue.yData}
        });
```

The error is

```
Conversion from decimal[] to double is not possible
```

Comment: You could change the type of `returnValue` to get the numbers from the DB as doubles instead of decimals.

Comment: I am using a straight away method to get the values. I can not change the return type of method `FillChart` as it is being used in other methods a lot.

`returnValue = SearchRepository.FillChart(id, Kanal);`

Comment: @Rik How could I convert? simple casting does not work

Answer (score 1):

Use Convert.ToDouble:

```
series1.Points.Add(new DataPoint
{
    AxisLabel = "Value1",
    YValues = returnValue.yData.Select(Convert.ToDouble).ToArray()
});
```

Comment: ArgumentNullExcepetion was unhandelled by user. It does not assign any value to YValue.

Comment: Maybe your array contains some values that are null?

Comment: it's collection stuff you can loop add with linq too like `returnValue.yData..ForEach(data => YValues.Add(Convert.ToDouble(data)));` and i was going to forget you do need in the constructor of `DataPoint` to initialize your YValues collection to something even empty array

Comment: @Alberto No I don't think so. If this is the case. I would have already exception. I am using my YData in other ways and its never complains about such exceptions